# sum range rows in data frame r

Tags: r, sum, range, rows

I have the data frame below, and would like to add one column `SumNextMonths` calculating for each month the sum of the `SalesForecasts` of the next 3months.

For example:

SumNextMonths in Feb = SalesForecastsof Mar + Apr +May.

```
d<- data.frame(Period =c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"),
SalesForecasts = c(100, 100, 200, 100, 300, 300, 100, 100, 200, 300,100, 100, 500, 500, 1000, 500, 1500, 1500, 500, 500, 1000, 1500, 500, 500))
```

Would anyone know how to proceed?

Thank you,
Cheers

Answer (score 1):

A generic answer could be:

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)
  d %>%
    mutate(temp_lead = lead(SalesForecasts, n = 1),
           SalesforNext3Months = rollapply(data = temp_lead, 
                                       width = 3, 
                                       FUN = sum, 
                                       align = "left", 
                                       fill = NA, 
                                       na.rm = T))%>%
    select(-temp_lead)
   Period SalesForecasts SalesforNext3Months
1     Jan            100                 400
2     Feb            100                 600
3     Mar            200                 700
4     Apr            100                 700
5     May            300                 500
6     Jun            300                 400
```

Comment: Thanks @Haboryme !

Comment: @Nico Np, if this answers your question consider accepting the answer ;)